# Notepad++ Find and Replace numbers regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

Trying to find and replace with a field name plus wild card values with a hard coded value.

```
 location = 123
 location = 456
 location = 789
```

I need to replace all the above with hard coded:

```
location = 999
```

I had started with this regex but not getting any matches

```
/location \= |\d*/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you using alternation operator there? There isn't any need for it. Also you need not escape `=` as it isn't a meta character in regex.

```
Find: location\s*=\s*\d+
Replace: location = 999
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the following expression

```
location = [0-9]{3}
```